# $|F^*|=1$ or a prime number of the form $2^p-1$ with a prime $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove: if $F$ is a finite field, then $H \cup \{0\} $ is a subfield of $F$ for every
subgroup $H$ of the multiplicative group $F^*$ if and only if the order of
$F^*$ is either $1$ or a prime number of the form $2^p-1$ with a prime $p$.

**My attempt**

Suppose that $|F|=r^n$, $r$ prime and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

As this is valid for all $H$ subgroup of the multiplicative group $F^*$, then in particular for $H=\{e\}$, $\hspace{0.2cm} $  $e$ the neutral of $F^*$, $e$ no zero. Como $H \cup \{0\} $ is an subfield of $F$, then $2=|H \cup \{0\}|=r^n$. Thus $r=2$ and $n=1$, but I do not know how to continue.

Please help.